# RestAssured : PATCH : 500 using rest assured but success in postman

Tags: java, api, automation, postman, rest-assured

I automated one of the patch request using Rest-assured, it was working before and suddenly it stopped working and throwing 500 error but the same requests works just fine in Post man. Please help

```
             given()
            .auth().preemptive().basic("user", "pwd")
            .headers(RequestUtils.getDefaultHeaders())
            .when()
            .patch(AUTH + "/" + REFERENCE + "/authorizations")
            .then()
            .statusCode(204).extract().response();
```

Patch command in debug would look like below,

```
http://localhost:8080/cxf/rest/tradeservice/branches/ABC/trade/abc123456/authorizations
```

it works perfectly fine in Postman

RequestUtils.getDefaultHeaders() is used to build header. similar request is working fine for POST request

```
 static Headers getDefaultHeaders() {
    List<Header> headerList = new ArrayList<>();
    headerList.add(new Header("id", "sit" + DataGeneration.generate8Digit()));
    headerList.add(new Header("Content-type", "application/json;version=1.0.0"));
    return new Headers(headerList);
}
```

getting below error in rest-assured

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <204> but was <500>.


at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:493)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:674)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:193)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:126)
at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:134)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:89)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.super$2$statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy:142)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
at LC_TEST.exportLcSaveAndAuthReturns201(TEST.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: are you using same headers, goto postman console and see what are the headers send see if you same headers you are getting ther error

Comment: yes, they are same headers ---  Content-Type:application/json;version=1.0.0
id:sit23456789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print the entire request & response in console and see what's the problem.
NOTE: I've removed status code assertion step due to avoid failing.

```
         given()
        .log().all()
        .auth().preemptive().basic("user", "pwd")
        .headers(RequestUtils.getDefaultHeaders())
        .when()
        .patch(AUTH + "/" + REFERENCE + "/authorizations")
        .then()
        .log().all()
        .extract().response();
```

Comment: Thank you villa_7, i could trace back the error using the log and fixed it. One of the header value was not acceptable by the application.